# MySQL - multiple INSERT INTO statements in query result in useless error message

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Both of these single statements work fine:

A:

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002),
  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  7.50, 7.50, ' -- 201900002'
);
```

B:

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002),
  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  3854.50, 2840.88, ' -- 201900002'
);
```

Now combine them to a single query:

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002),
  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  7.50, 7.50, ' -- 201900002'
);
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002),
  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  3854.50, 2840.88, ' -- 201900002'
);
```

And I get the useless generic MySQL error at the beginning of the second statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'INSERT INTO `table1` (`relationId`, `string1`, `date1`, `date2`,
> `string2' at line 10

What am I missing here? Where's the problem? I am quite sure I have used the same script to generate a query a few months ago and it ran correctly.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in a (now missing) comment, this could be transformed to INSERT ... SELECT statement. So I tried it, but ran into the exact same problem. Single INSERT validates, consecutive INSERTs throw UMEM™ (Unhelpful MySQL Error Message):

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
SELECT id,  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  7.50, 7.50, ' -- 201900002' FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002;
INSERT INTO `table1`
    (`relationId`,
   `string1`, `date1`, `date2`, `string2`,
   `decimal1`, `decimal2`, `string3`)
SELECT id,  'UNK', '2019-02-27', '2019-03-14', 'ABCDEF',
  7.50, 7.50, ' -- 201900002' FROM table2 WHERE serial = 0002;
```

Comment: Where are you running the queries from?

Comment: Sqlectron DB client, connected to remote MariaDB server. The same error is thrown on these online validators though:
https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/
https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: your query are correctly run in sql server not a problem in your query . i think problem in sql platform when run your query

Comment: Have you try to use `union all` to merge you two values statements ?

Comment: @Tohm I tried in a validator, the error remains.

Comment: @s.ch that's interesting, sqlectron and two online validators all throw the same error

Comment: Small point: you've tagged this with both MySQL and MariaDB. The two products have diverged such that they are now different products. It might not make a difference here, but it would be better to know which if the two you're actually using.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the server is using MariaDB, the online validators I tried were for MySQL. That's why I used both tags here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is strange.

**a) The actual error for me:**
Source spreadsheet contained a wrongly formatted number on row 516, resulting in the excel `#VALUE!` error making its way into my generated SQL where a DECIMAL value should have been. MySQL stating an error on line 9 did not really help me finding the problem somewhere around line 5000.

**b) Online validators:**
Why online validators stated the exact same error even when there was no bad value in the statements remains a mystery. In fact, they still throw the error now on the exact same SQL that just ran correctly on the server.